# How to use the find function for Python 3.4.1?

Tags: python, find

Here is my code:

```
import re
sentence = raw_input("Write your sentence here ")
word = raw_input("What word would you like to find the position of?")
for i in re.finditer(word, sentence):
    print i.start(), i.end()
```

This works in python 2.7.3 but I need it to work in 3.4. When I run the code in 3.4 it gives `"i" as an invalid syntax`.

Is there a way of altering the code slightly so that it will work or will a whole new method need to be used instead?

Also the program can't be case sensitive.

Thanks.

Comment: [`raw_input`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) is now called [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input).

Comment: And `print` is a function now and requires to be called as one: `print(…)`.

Comment: [What’s New In Python 3.0](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html) may be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [input()](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#input) instead of `raw_input()` and use [print()](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#print) function to print anything in `python 3.x`.

The following code works for `python 3.x`.

```
import re
sentence = input("Write your sentence here ")
word = input("What word would you like to find the position of? ")
for i in re.finditer(word, sentence):
    print(i.start(), i.end())
```

Sample I/O:

```
Write your sentence here I love asian food, specially indian food.
What word would you like to find the position of? food
13 17
36 40
```

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to mention that I tried changing raw input to just input. The only thing I didn't do was move the print to become a function. Works great now.

Comment: @DaniM you are welcome. if my answer helped you, you can accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
raw_input -> input
```

The difference is that `raw_input()` does not exist in Python 3.x, while `input()` does. Actually, the old `raw_input()` has been renamed to `input()`

Also, `print` become `print()` as well.

Comment: also `print` is now a function

Comment: @Duncan, Thanks, added to answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help.